# Why the "archaic" word 'parlous' is still in use?

Tags: word-choice

The online Oxford English dictionary deems `parlous` [as *archaic*](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+parlous) but the word is still used in a major US newspaper [*Wall Street Journal* article](https://www.wsj.com/articles/italy-holds-elections-as-economic-clouds-gather-11664108143) today:

> The likely right-wing government will face difficult decisions over how to protect Italian households and businesses from sky-high prices for electricity and natural gas. Italy’s **parlous** public finances allow limited scope for fiscal largess. EU governments have so far struggled to agree on a collective intervention to tackle energy costs.

Why in this context the archaic word `parlous` is preferred?  Why not use "precarious" or "perilous"?

If the meaning used is not archaic but [formal](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/parlous) (Cambridge dictionary) or [much less preferred compared to "perilous"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/parlous) (Merriam-Webster "Did you know" note), why does the online Oxford dictionary label this usage archaic?

Comment: It is not really archaic when used in that sense. There are other uses of the word that are indeed archaic.

Comment: Parlous is not labelled 'archaic' [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/parlous), only 'formal'.

Comment: @Peter I see.  Maybe the question should be why Oxford dictionary labels it archaic?  [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/parlous) labels that meaning "formal".

Comment: Dictionaries do not always agree, and you would be sensible to consult more than one. Whether a word is old-fashioned, obsolete, archaic, etc, is ultimately a matter of opinion. Words tend to survive longer in educated or formal usage.

Comment: If the Wall Street Journal uses it, it's fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **Full** Oxford English Dictionary doesn't label ***parlous*** as archaic, but it certainly has [very little currency](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=parlous%2Cprecarious%2Cperilous&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) compared to the "synonyms" ***precarious*** and ***perilous***...

[image]

BUT - in the specific context of ***financial / economic*** "ill-health", ***parlous*** [has actually *gained* traction](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=finances%20are%20in%20a%20parlous%2Cfinances%20are%20in%20a%20precarious&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=10) over the past century...

[image]

---

That's why I put ***synonyms*** in "scare quotes" above. Even if most dictionaries don't explicitly mention it, ***parlous*** carries much stronger implications of ***fiscal*** problems than alternatives.

Obviously many writers naturally choose the term with the strongest links to their specific intended sense, so increasingly we see journalists and economists use ***parlous*** when writing about national economies lately (they're not just showing off their wide vocabularies! :)

Comment: This answer makes a lot of sense and helps me to use dictionaries and Google ngrams better to guide my own word choices as well as to discern the motivation behind literary / academic / cultured prose in today's media.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The expression 'in a parlous state' is one of those archaic phrases that have been preserved in modern usage, like fossils, even though they include otherwise obsolete words. Other examples are 'with bated breath' and 'in high dudgeon'.

Because of this, people *do* sometimes use the word 'parlous' on its own, knowing that its meaning will be understood from the phrase 'parlous state'.

Comment: And I see little wrong with doing that. If I see or hear of something said to be *archaic* it induces me to want immediately to start using it.

Answer (score -6):

The word "***perilous***" has the same meaning as:

> - hazardous.
> - dangerous.

People use the word "***perilous***" when being mellow-dramatic.

The word "***perilous***" is used by ostentatious people.

The author of the news article wanted to make themselves sound highly-educated.

Aristocrats use the word "peril" and "perilous".

Working class Americans (financially poor or middle class people) use the words "danger" and "dangerous"

There is an old aphorism which says, "we live in ***perilous*** times"

The author was trying to convey a particulair tone. Rich people use a particulair tone of voice when they use the word "*perilous*"

The author sounds hauty and dramatic.

The word "perilous" is used in an exaggerated tone of voice. They would sound breathless. It is over-the-top or over done.

People who fien their emotions use the word "perilous".

The saying, "We live in ***perilous*** times" is said in the same tone of voice as "***woe is me***."

The author of the news article is puttinf on aires. The author aims to appear more intelligent and well-educated than they actually are.

The author of the news article was trying to make themselves look important.

Only Frumps use the word "***perilous***".

Comment: I got mellow-dramatic when I smoked weed at acting school.

Comment: Perilous? The question was about "parlous".

Comment: This answer is all about "*perilous*", but the4 question is about "*parlous*", a different word, the meaning of which is closer to "precarious" or "shaky" than to "dangerous".  The word "*parlous*" is IMO not srchaic, although it is somewhst unusual. The answer by @FumbleFingers describes its usage well in a financial context.

Comment: I'm sad no-one like my 'mellow' comment.